# Malformed Access Token for azure graph api

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, adal, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get the azure graph api token not the 365 I have that portion working.

I am also using adal4service to acquire the token but i cannot seem to get the token back correctly.

```
this.http.get('https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6',
  {
    headers: new Headers({ "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.Adal4Service.acquireToken("https://graph.windows.net") })
  })
  .subscribe(res => {
    // Check the response status before trying to display files
    if (res.status === 200){
      this.result = res.json().value;
  }
    else
      alert("An error occurred calling the Microsoft Graph: " + res.status);
  });
```

Comment: I am not sure how to get the access token from azure graph api so i can fetch information about the tenant active directory. I can get the new graph api access token with user login but it does not allow me to get the information i need.

Comment: Working now.. looking to see what i did wrong.